# Given any positive real numbers $a,b,c$, we have $(a^{2}+2)(b^{2}+2)(c^{2}+2)\geq 9(ab+bc+ca)$

Tags: inequality

I have a  beautiful  inequality, but I can only prove part of cases. Given any positive real numbers $a,b,c$, we have

$$(a^{2}+2)(b^{2}+2)(c^{2}+2)\geq 9(ab+bc+ca)$$

How can we prove this statement?

Comment: This "let us discuss" doesn't fit the Q/A format of this site.

Comment: Could you show what part(s) you worked on?

Comment: we find that if a,b,c are very big or very small, we can easy prove the result.

Comment: Rather than ask for a discussion try and ask for a proof. That way people can answer concisely and  you would fit the MSE style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you can use Cauchy Schwarz inequality to prove stronger inequality
$$(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)\ge 3(a+b+c)^2\ge 9(ab+bc+ac)$$
Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$(b^2+1)(1+c^2)\ge (b+c)^2, (b^2+c^2)(1+1)\ge (b+c)^2$$
so
$$(b^2+2)(c^2+2)=(b^2+1)(1+c^2)+b^2+c^2+3\ge (b+c)^2+\dfrac{1}{2}(b+c)^2+3=3[1+\dfrac{(b+c)^2}{2}]$$

and use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$(a^2+2)[1+\dfrac{(b+c)^2}{2}]\ge (a+b+c)^2$$

Comment: The LHS inequality is not so obvious to me, could you please explain it?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio,hello,I have edit it